# Powershell create object from multiple files

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I am making a PSObject from a json file

bar.json

```
{
  "derp": {
   "buzz": 42 
   },
   "woot":  {
     "toot": 9000
   }
}
```

I can make a PSCustomObject form the json using ConvertFrom-Json

```
$foo = Get-Content .\bar.json -Raw |ConvertFrom-Json
$foo.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

However if I try and splat multiple json files, I get an array

```
$foo = Get-Content .\*.json -Raw |ConvertFrom-Json
$foo.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    Object[]                                 System.Array
```

In order to iterate over $foo, I need 2 different code paths depending on the object type.

**Can I get a single object from multiple json files?

If not, how would I compress an array of objects into a single object?**

I've tried to make a new object `$bar` that contains all the array items of `$foo`

```
$bar = new-object psobject
$bar | add-member -name $foo[0].psobject.properties.name -value $foo[0].'derp' -memberType NoteProperty
```

**Update**
Per Walter Mitty's request. If I load a single file and run `$foo[0]`

```
$foo = Get-Content .\bar.json -Raw |ConvertFrom-Json
$foo[0].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

$foo[0]

derp                                                    woot
------------                                            ------------
@{Provisioners=System.Object[]; OS=windows; Size=; V... @{Provisioners=System.Object[]; OS=windows; Size=; V...
```

**Solution**

I initially implemented AP's answer, but later refactored it to use mklement0 answer.

While $allObjects is an array, it still allows me to reference values by name which is what I was looking for

```
$allObjects = @(
    Get-ChildItem '.\foo' -Filter *.json -Recurse | Get-Content -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
)

# iterating over nested objects inside an array is hard.
# make it easier by moving all array objects into 1 parent object where 
# the 'key' is the name (opposed to AP's answer where filename = key)
$newObject = New-Object PSObject
foreach ($i in $allObjects) {
    $i.psobject.members | ?{$_.Membertype -eq 'noteproperty'} |%{$newObject | add-member $_.Name $_.Value}
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if two json files/objects have the same property with different values?

Comment: Good point, I would expect an error if any key is not unique

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think an array of objects is an object.

Comment: Try "$foo[0].gettype" or "$foo[0] | gm" to find out more about the first entry in $foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is an Array of JSON objects which are parsed from the different files:

```
$final = @{}

# Loop Thru All JSON Files, and add to $Final[<name>] = <JSON>
ls .\*.json | % {
  $o = cat $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
  $final[$_.name] = [PsCustomObject]$o
}
$final = [PsCustomObject]$final
```

This will produce a Name -> Data map for all your JSON files as a nested `PSObject`

Comment: In the linux world, parsing the output of `ls` is discouraged. Is windows the same?

Comment: Nothing in PowerShell is actually returning just strings, they're objects with fields..

Comment: @spuder ls and cat in powershell are inly aliase to `get-childitem` and `get-content` @AP. I get this error with your code `The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression.`

Answer (score 2):

[AP.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41066617/45375) is an elegant solution for creating a single top-level object (`[pscustomobject]` instance) that:

- houses all JSON-converted objects as *properties named for their input filenames*.

  - E.g., `$final` would contain a `bar.json` property whose value is the object equivalent of the JSON string from the question.
  - A caveat is that with duplicate filenames the last file processed would "win".

<sup>See bottom for a usage note re Unix-style aliases `ls` and `cat`.</sup>

---

To **get an *array* of all converted-from-JSON objects**, the following is sufficient:

```
$allObjects = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.json | Get-Content -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

<sup>Note that if you only need a *single* directory's JSON files,

`$allObjects = @(Get-Content -Path *.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json)` works too.</sup>

Note the use of `@(...)`, the *array* subexpression operator, which ensures that what is returned is treated as an *array*, even if only a *single* object is returned.

- By default, or when you use `$(...)`, the *regular* subexpression operator, PowerShell unwraps any (potentially nested) single-item collection and returns only the item itself; see [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators).

---

**A note on the use of Unix-style aliases `ls` and `cat`** for PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Content` cmdlets, respectively:

- Now that PowerShell is cross-platform, these aliases only exist in the *Windows* edition of PowerShell, whereas a decision was made to omit them from PowerShell Core on Unix platforms, so as not to shadow the standard Unix utilities of the same name.
- It is **better to get into the habit of using PowerShell's *own* aliases**, which follow prescribed naming conventions and do not conflict with platform-specific utilities.

  - E.g., `gci` can be used for `Get-ChildItem`, and `gc` for `Get-Content`
  - For the naming conventions behind PowerShell's own aliases, see the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx).